# Why does AngularFire2 Query not work with combinelatest or forkjoin

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, angularfire2

I have two simple lists in Firebase.
One is a list of Posts, the other a list of Images.
When an image belongs to a post it has a postKey set on it that points to the post.

E.g.

```
posts: {
    $key: 'P1': {
        name: 'a post'
    }
}

images: {
    $key: 'I1': {
        name: 'image one',
        postKey: 'P1'
    },
    $key: 'I2': {
        name: 'image two',
        postKey: 'P2'
    }
}
```

Now, I want to write a simple query that fetches a post and all it's associated images

So I set up two observables, one of them a query and use combineLatest.
(Ideally I would use forkJoin - but need to get this working first)

But it does not work - the observable never fires:

```
    let key= 'P1';
   const imagesQuery$ = this.db.list(this.IMAGES, {
      query: {
        orderByChild: 'postKey',
        equalTo: key
      }
    });

    const posts$ = this.db.object(`${this.POSTS}/${key}`);

    return Observable.combineLatest(posts$, imagesQuery$, (post, images) => {
      post.images= images.map(image=> image);
      return post;
    })
```

However if I change the query to a simple list, it works - although of course there is no filtering  so ALL images are assigned to the post.

```
    let key= 'P1';
    const images$ = this.db.list(`${this.IMAGES}`);

    const posts$ = this.db.object(`${this.POSTS}/${key}`);

    return Observable.combineLatest(posts$, images$, (post, images) => {
      post.images= images.map(image=> image);
      return post;
    })
```

What am I missing???

Comment: Did you manage to resolve this because I am in the same situation right now.